# How to get the number of calls of the text file at XCODE 5

Tags: ios7, xcode5

I use iPhone 4s with XCODE 5 and want to know how to get a count/number of calls/openings of specific text file in my application directory.

Thanks for help

Comment: Any idea how to get calls counter?